# I declare query at the method using the @Query annotation,but failed to run the test application ，the code as follows

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this problem in the images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

the run result:
[image]

Comment: You should not post images like that but preferably copy/paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to replace `field` with `match` and that will work